# Input value as an array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

"->im getting this string (' -->['a', 'b', 'c']<-- ') as input value, so i need to get from input an array like this -->['a', 'b', 'c']<--"

let arr = target.value.slice(2, -2);
arr = arr.split('', '');
So it's working like this, maybe there is another way (easier)???

Comment: you need to make this question a little better. add some information, format and include full code and mention errors

Answer (score 2):

Fix whatever's generating the input so that it gives you proper JSON instead - for example:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

(JSON is the de-facto standard for serialized data, at least on the front-end. Something that is *not* giving you JSON can often be considered to be effectively broken)

Then you can turn it into an object with `JSON.parse`.

```js
const dataStr = '["a", "b", "c"]';
console.log(JSON.parse(dataStr));
```